# MySQL Update Statement Returning No Affected Rows

Tags: php, mysql

I'm struggling to find an error in this. I am running an Update command in MySQL through PHP.

```
UPDATE `diary` SET `meds_taken` = 'Y' AND `time_taken` = '9AM' AND 
`stress_level` = '7' AND `adverse` = 'N' AND `events` = 'testing' AND 
`journal_date` = '2015-07-14' AND `submit_time` = NOW() WHERE `hash` = 
'a9fc195dc62624db5fddd7134392ce67'
```

It does not return any errors, but affects `0` rows. Running the command directly in PHPMyAdmin has the identical effect.

To confirm, there is a row with the hash:

```
SELECT * FROM `diary` WHERE `hash` = 'a9fc195dc62624db5fddd7134392ce67'
```

Yields one row. All the updated columns are of type `VARCHAR` except for "events" which is of type `TEXT` and "submit_time" which is of type `DATE`.

I feel like I made a typo somewhere but cannot find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try commas, rather than ANDs:

```
UPDATE `diary`
SET `meds_taken` = 'Y',
    `time_taken` = '9AM',
    `stress_level` = '7',
    `adverse` = 'N',
    `events` = 'testing',
    `journal_date` = '2015-07-14',
    `submit_time` = NOW()
WHERE `hash` = 'a9fc195dc62624db5fddd7134392ce67';
```

Comment: ... facepalm. I feel so silly. Clearly I cannot write MySQL syntax that late at night.